# C# Linq to use CellEndEdit of DataGrid to update database

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagrid

I am wondering how to reference columns and row with regard to an edited cell using Linq. I have a DataGrid with 3 columns which will received integers between 1 and 100 in them (in the 3rd column). Once the cell edit has ended, I need to verify that the integers are between 1 and 100, and if so, insert them into the database. My problem is, I don't know how to reference the cell that was selected. I'm very new to this, so is there a simple way to reference the column/row of an edited cell, and the column/rows of the corresponding data in the same row.

I figured I will need something starting like this:

```
private void gvMarks_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if () //if new data between 1 and 100
        {
            //enter into database using Linq
            using (DataModel db = new DataModel())
            {
                //Linq code here

                db.SaveChanges();
                this.student_CourseTableAdapter.Fill(this.libraryDBDataSet.Student_Course);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Message");
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out how to do it. Just for context, I am updating a column titled 'Mark' on a db table called 'Student_Course'. The 3 columns in the table are CID, SID, Mark. Here's the code:

```
private void gvMarks_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
            int marks = Convert.ToInt32(gvMarks.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value);
            int CIDref = Convert.ToInt32(gvMarks.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);
            int SIDref = Convert.ToInt32(gvMarks.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value);
            if (marks <= 100 && marks >= 0)
            {
                using (DataModel db = new DataModel())
                {
                    Student_Course newMark = db.Student_Course.First(s => s.CID == CIDref && s.SID == SIDref);
                    newMark.Mark = marks;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Marks updated");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Out of Range");
            }
    }
```

Comment: You need to be in a repeating loop, and replace e.RowIndex the line in the loop: dataGridView1.Rows [j]. See previous EDIT

Comment: is always the first line just replace e.RowIndex by 0

Comment: Column[2] is edited. I then need the details in Column[0] and Column[1] so that the Linq code can updated the database in the correct place. Column[0] and Column[1] are both unique relationships in the database, so there is only one instance where they will both be in the same Row in a specific combination. The Linq code is basically saying "insert value from Edited Cell into Row where Columns are equal to the corresponding column values in the edited cell".

Comment: but you need to go through all the lines to ensure that the values are correct, for it needs a covering for the lines in columns 0 and 1

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. This current code that I posted is doing what I need it to do. It doesn't need to go through each row. It just needs to find the row with the corresponding data.

Comment: so tell me how you gonna do to check all the lines without a repeat loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["columnName"].Index && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.RowCount; j++)
        {
            int value = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["columnName"].Value.toString())

            if ( value > 1 && value < 10)
            {
                //Some Code;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error Message");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it says 'Object reference not set to an instance of object'

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["marks"].Index && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        bool outOfRange;

        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.RowCount; j++)
        {
            int value = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["marks"].Value.toString())

            if ( value > 100 || value < 0)
            {
                outOfRange = true;
            }
        }

        if(!outOfRange)
        {
            using (DataModel db = new DataModel())
            {
                //sure that the code is correct?
                Student_Course newMark = db.Student_Course.First(s => s.CID == CIDref && s.SID == SIDref);
                newMark.Mark = marks;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Marks updated");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Out of Range");
        }
    }
}
```